# Run apache tomcat server in docker container

Tags: apache, tomcat, containers, docker

I have a .war file I would like to run and start a server inside a docker container. Tomcat 8 with java 8.

I am using

```
docker pull komu/tomcat8-java8
```

Then I am not sure how to start the docker container containing my .war file. I also have a URL for it I would like to use.

Answer (score -1):

Nice long post about it, the part you want is about half way down: Installing Java
http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/06/deploy-java-apps-with-docker-awesome/